# Batch extract information from text file

Tags: batch-file

i need to extract some info from a text file. This is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<XMLEDIT version="XMLEDIT TEST Favorites">
   <Name title="NAME_1" url="www.etc.com">
      <Source>mms://MYSOURCE_1.com</Source>
   </Name>
   <Name title="NAME_2" url="www.etc.com/">
      <Source>http://MYSOURCE_2.com</Source>
   </Name>
   <Name title="NAME_3" url="www.etc.com/">
      <Source>http://MYSOURCE_3.com</Source>
   </Name>
</XMLEDIT>
```

I need the text between quotes after Name Title= so NAME_1, NAME_2 and NAME_3 and the text between tags "Source"

The output i want is:

```
1
1 NAME_1
1,source,mms://MYSOURCE_1.com
2
2 NAME_2
2,source,http://MYSOURCE_2.com
3
3 NAME_3
3,source,http://MYSOURCE_3.com
```

I have do the second part, extract the text between tags but i don't know how to make the Name Title= part and make everything in one script

My attempt:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Num=0
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('find "<Source>" ^< "C:\Test.txt"') Do (
 set /a Num+=1
 echo !Num!
 echo !Num! here title
 echo !Num!,source,%%a
)
pause
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you *have* to do this in Batch? PowerShell has powerful XML capabilities built-in, which will make your life hundreds of times easier!

Comment: Yes, i prefer in batch ( or VBS at least ) because i know it, Powershell is a unknow language for me so in future if i need to edit it i don't know how to manage it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34872773.txt"
SET /a section=0
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2,3delims=<=>" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%b"=="Name title" CALL :setname %%c
 IF "%%b"=="Source" CALL :report "%%c"
 
)

GOTO :EOF

:report
SET /a section +=1
ECHO %section%
ECHO %section% %name%
ECHO %section%,%~1

GOTO :EOF

:setname
SET "name=%~1"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34872773.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Read the file, line-by-line, tokenising on `<`,`=` and `>` to %%A,%%b,%%c

- %%a will receive the indenting spaces
- %%b will receive the token string
- %%c will receive the data of interest

If `%%b` is `Name title` then execute the subroutine `setname` passing the part of interest from the remainder of the line. The first string here is a quoted name. The subroutine simple takes the first parameter it is given and assigns that string, without the quotes to `name`.

When a `Source` tag is encountered, produce the report; bump the `section` counter and spit out the remainder.

If you want to direct the output to a file, delete the file first and append `>>"filename"` to the `call :report` line.